# Chaining a path of 3D bezier segments

Tags: unity-game-engine, curve, bezier

I am writing a simple path editor in Unity3D by storing a series of points, in/out tangents, and drawing a bezier between each pair of points:

[image]

The data for the path:

[image]

What I'm finding is the tangents don't behave as I would expect. I'm very much used to image editing applications where the tangents are actually tangental to the curve:

[image]

But if you look back to my first image you can see that the tangents have to be moved to more perpendicular angles to get a smooth shape.

At this point I think there are a few possibilities:

1. There's a stupid mistake in my code somewhere.
2. My understanding of beziers is poor, and I'm incorrect in assuming I
   can simply chain beziers in this fashion.
3. Maybe my data is incompatible somehow with Unity's bezier drawing (I've briefly read about linear, cubic, quadratic etc beziers).

Does anyone have any advice for me on how I can improve my usage of beziers?

Thanks,
Ves

Comment: *"There's a stupid mistake in my code somewhere."* .... where can we find it?

Comment: It was just a hypothesis. All paths reach:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.DrawBezier.html

`Handles.DrawBezier(pointA.position, pointB.position, pointA.outTangent, pointB.inTangent,...);`

When I log these values they match the provided data.

Comment: I mean, where can we find your code? If you want us to solve a problem with it, show it to us.

Comment: Bezier curve chaining requires work for a smooth path.  You need to at least guarantee first order continuity (tangents match at control points).  Or use this [community script](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Interpolate) for canned interpolation (see catmull rom)

Comment: @Vesuvian: please provide the relevant code.

Comment: The "model": http://pastebin.com/JCb8wtPY The "view": http://pastebin.com/p4v620DN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, I figured out the problem.

The unity documentation is extremely unclear on what the tangents are supposed to be. In my code I was using local vectors for the tangents, when the DrawBezier method actually wants the absolute positions of the tangent points.

I've been able to fix the curve drawing by doing the following:

```
Handles.DrawBezier(pointA.position,
                   pointB.position,
                   pointA.position + pointA.outTangent,
                   pointB.position + pointB.inTangent,
                   Handles.color,
                   null,
                   1.0f);
```

[image]

The solution made sense when I understood what Heisenbug was saying about the 4 points in a cubic bezier. Thanks a ton guys!

Comment: glad you figured it out!